# Why don't my text-message conversations pile up?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I've recently installed a new version of my favorite rom "Codec ROM" in version 10.1, previously I was using v7.5, which was working like a charm.
I have done a full wipe, and installed the version 10. Everything works correctly.

When I start receiving some text message, every new one is created in an other conversation, instead of being added to the corresponding contact conversation.

So I try to re-wipe, re-install the rom, and the same problem occurs.

Device: International SGS 3 
ROM: Codec ROM 10 (JellyBean)

Any idea on how to fix?